# Can I turn coarse coarnmeal into fine with a blender?

Tags: baking, corn

I wonder if running your cornmeal (dry) through a blender for a couple of minutes might break it down a little? Like when you want finer sugar.

Note: taken from [a deleted answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/37925/1672) to [How do I eliminate cornmeal grittiness?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/28118/1672)

Comment: There are many instructions on the internet for grinding dent corn (field corn) in a blender, so it is likely to work.  I have not tried it, though, so I am not making this an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory it's possible. However, not all blenders are created equal. [This link](http://www.foxinthekitchenblog.com/gluten-free-flours/gluten-free-flours-a-to-l/corn-flour-masa-harina-cornmeal/) mentions doing it, but in my experience to blend something into a super fine powder (a flour-like consistency) you need a really powerful machine like a Vita-mix. Also you may get inconsistencies in texture with a blender. This is one reason professional coffee bars use burr grinders instead of blade grinders: to achieve a consistent grind.